# Types for New Google login api implementation (GIS)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

According to the documentation by google in this link, https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis#gis-only,    **https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client** is now used for auth. But I use typescript in reactjs, is there any @types package for the api that includes oauth2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the desired @types package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/google.accounts
I've used it successfully.

Comment: Can you please share the code?